# Let $f_n = (\frac{1}{n})\chi_{[0,n]}$ and $f = 0$. Show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, uniform-convergence

> Let $f_n = (\frac{1}{n})\chi_{[0,n]}$ and $f = 0$. Show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$.

I have never done an example of convergence of sequences that have characteristic (indicator) functions and honestly have no idea how to work with them in limits. Can anyone please explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $g_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ if and only if 
$$\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|g_n(x) - g(x)|\to 0$$
as $n\to \infty$. In your case we have that

$$\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|\left(\frac1n\right) \chi_{[0,n]}(x) - 0\right| = \frac1n\to 0$$ 
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

[Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence):$\forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists N: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, n\geq N: |f_n(x) - f(x)|<\varepsilon $.

So lets take $N: = [\frac{1}{\varepsilon}]+1$ and we have

$\forall \varepsilon>0  \ \exists N=[\frac{1}{\varepsilon}]+1: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, n\geq N: |\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[0;n]} - 0|<\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon $

as indicator is either $\frac{1}{n}$ or  $0$.

Comment: Thank you! :). Just to confirm, if we had $(f_n) = (\frac{1}{n})\chi_{[n, + \infty)}$, this "proof" would have been exactly the same, right? Since $| \frac{1}{n}\chi_{[n, + \infty)} - 0|  \le \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$. Correct?

Comment: @user290425  I think yes. The definition says about the convergence for every $x$. The second answer uses criterion via $sup$ and you can see that it also works, as the $sup|\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[n,\infty)}| = 1/n$.